Mongoose create function not check parameter types
Im currently developing a web app with nestjs. I must to use mongoose as orm. But i had some issues with mongoose while develops. I guess mongoose has not typescript native. For example create function allows anything in parameter include the keys which i dont have in my schema. Im using a soft delete library and i wrote some classes to implement their props to my schema.
This is my base schema class :
import mongoose, { Callback, Document } from 'mongoose';
import { SoftDeleteDocument } from 'mongoose-delete';

export class DbSubDocument extends Document<mongoose.Types.ObjectId> {
  override _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
}

export class DbDocument extends DbSubDocument implements SoftDeleteDocument {
  delete: (deleteBy?: string | mongoose.Types.ObjectId | Callback<this>, fn?: Callback<this>) => Promise<this>;
  restore: (fn?: Callback<this>) => Promise<this>;
}

This is my schema:
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { AccountingCustomCategory } from 'src/accounting-custom-category/entities/accounting-custom-category.entity';
import { DbDocument } from 'src/common/types/mongoose-document';

import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { PartyType_Type, PartyType_Array } from 'src/accounting/types/party.type';
import { VoucherType_Type, VoucherType_Array } from 'src/accounting/types/voucher.type';
import { Currency_Array, Currency_Type } from 'src/common/types/currency.type';

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Accounting extends DbDocument {
  @Prop({ required: true, type: Date })
  date: Date;

  @Prop({ required: true, type: Number })
  credit: number;

  @Prop({ required: true, type: Number })
  debit: number;

  @Prop({
    required: true,
    type: String,
    enum: PartyType_Array,
  })
  partyType: PartyType_Type;

  @Prop({ required: false, type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId })
  partyID?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ required: false, type: String, enum: VoucherType_Array })
  voucherType?: VoucherType_Type;

  @Prop({ required: false, type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId })
  voucherID?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ required: false, type: String })
  description?: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, type: String, enum: Currency_Array })
  currency: Currency_Type;

  @Prop({
    required: false,
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: AccountingCustomCategory.name,
  })
  customCategoryID?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
}

export const AccountingSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Accounting);

And this is my service function:
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { SoftDeleteModel } from 'mongoose-delete';
import { Accounting } from 'src/accounting/entities/accounting.entity';

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { PartyType_Enum } from 'src/accounting/types/party.type';
import { VoucherType_Enum } from 'src/accounting/types/voucher.type';
import { Currency_Enum } from 'src/common/types/currency.type';

@Injectable()
export class AccountingService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Accounting.name) private accountingModel: SoftDeleteModel<Accounting>) {}

  // All of service methods is internal function that will be only used by the other service methods
  async createAccountingRecord(data: {
    credit: number;
    debit: number;
    partyType: PartyType_Enum;
    partyID: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
    voucherType: VoucherType_Enum;
    voucherID: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
    description: string;
    currency: Currency_Enum;
    customCategoryID: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  }) {
    // typescript has no error on about notExistKey which is not exist in my actual schema
    return await this.accountingModel.create({ date: new Date(), ...data, notExistKey: 'asd' });
  }
}

Also there is my tsconfig:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "docs", "public"]
}

I want to the typescript shows me where i added or forget the wrong keys.
How can i make this works ?
